# changes not reflected in the variable values passed between C# code and C++ code

Tags: c#, c++

I have an application which uses C# front end and a C++ DLL as the backend. I am trying to pass an array from C# code to the C++ code in the DLL which changes the values in that array. But when I try to retrieve the values of the array from C# code after the call is made to the C++ DLL function, the changes are not being reflected. I want the changes to be reflected. Please help me in this regard.

Thanks,
Rakesh.

---

The following are the signatures of the functions that I am using.

In C#:

```
testStruct(structs, len);
```

structs is the array of structures that I am passing.

In C++:

```
extern "C"  __declspec(dllexport)  void __cdecl  testStruct(structure1*  arrStruct, int len)
```

arrStruct is the array of structures which receives the ones passed from C#.

Comment: Please post the signature being used (or else look up [pinvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array is being marshalled **by value** to the C++ DLL, which means your C++ DLL is working on a copy of the original array. The array needs to be marshalled **by reference** in order for your C++ code to manipulate the same array which your C# code is referring to.

Rather than investigating methods of marhsalling the array by reference you may want to consider changing your C++ interface so that the manipulated array is returned to your C# code as, for example, a return value.

Answer (score 1):

In your native code:

```
void fill(int* buffer, size_t length)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    buffer[i] = i;
}
```

In your C# code:

```
[DllImport("Foo")]
static void fill([Out] int[] buffer, UIntPtr length);
```

See [OutAttribute Class reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.outattribute(VS.80).aspx).

You can also use `[In, Out]` if your native method has to the content first before modifying it.